# sql count base table with subtable condition

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
user_table

|   uid  |
----------
|    1   |  
|    2   | 
|    3   | 
|    4   |
```

user_role_table

```
|   uid       |   role      |  
-----------------------------  
|   1         |   Main1Role |  
|   1         |   Main2Role | 
|   1         |   Sub1Role  | 
|   1         |   Sub2Role  | 
|   2         |   Main1Role | 
|   2         |   Sub1Role  | 
|   3         |   Main1Role | 
|   3         |   Main2Role | 
|   4         |   Sub1Role  | 
|   4         |   Sub2Role  |
```

if the user has a main role he should not be counted for subrole.

uid 1 is counted in Main
uid 2 is counted in Main
uid 3 is counter in Main
uid 4 is counted in sub

it is like sum of users with higher priority given to main user

Expected Output
MainRoleCount: 3
SubRoleCount: 1

Comment: So your expected output is: Main1Role = Count 3 (1,2,3), Main2Role = Count 2 (1,3), Sub1Role = 1 (4), Sub2Role = 1 (4) ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Are they really named "Main1Role" and "Sub2Role"?

Comment: Added a solution for your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your expected output.

I understood: You want to get the number of uids of every role. But if one uid is in both, a main and a sub role, the count has to ignore the uid for the total of the sub roles.

So, in your example the counts are as follows:

- Main1Role is for uids 1,2,3: Count = 3
- Main2Role is for uids 1,3: Count = 2
- Sub1Role is for uids 1,2,4, but 1 and 2 have a main role, so it is only for 4: Count = 1
- Sub2Role is for 1,4, but 1 has a main role, so it is only for 4: Count = 1

---

Assuming this is what you want:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c88fb3830768ad3dd1fd22ae27dea006)

```
SELECT
    role,
    SUM (
        CASE WHEN role IN ('Main1Role', 'Main2Role') THEN 1
             ELSE CASE WHEN ARRAY['Main1Role', 'Main2Role'] && array_agg THEN 0
                       ELSE 1 END
        END
    )
FROM (
SELECT
    *,
    array_agg(role) OVER (PARTITION BY uid)
FROM
    user_role_table
) s
GROUP BY role
```

---

For added expected output. Same idea, but subquerying the role types:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=494bf0f03a7ae6edf6b4c5372ab6aa75)

Comment: Lets consider in a company there are 3 people , i need to seperate Managers and Developers, U1 is [Team Lead, Developer] U2 is [Team Lead],  U3 is [Developer]. The team lead is considered as manager role , U1, U2 is counted for managers and U3 is counted for Developer , eventhough the U1 is Developer+Manager the Team lead role overrides this @S-Man

Answer (score 0):

You can try this simple query to get your desired output-

```
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN role_name = 'M' THEN 'MainRoleCount'
    WHEN role_name = 'S' THEN 'SubRoleCount'
END role_name,
COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT uid,MIN(LEFT(role,1)) role_name
    FROM your_table
    GROUP BY uid
)A
GROUP BY role_name
```

Output will be-

```
role_name   Count
Main1Role   3
Sub1Role    1
```

Comment: Yes as role names are mentioned by the OP. So no confusion that this will work.